# Aggregating multiple Hibernate Formulas due to performance reasons

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to change @Formula to something else or aggregate them so that one select would be performed? SOME_TABLE has 80 properties and I don't want to load the whole entity, just 4 columns.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    protected String id;

    @Version
    protected Long version;

    @Formula("(select a from SOME_TABLE ST ST.some_id = id)")
    private Long property1;

    @Formula("(select b from SOME_TABLE ST ST.some_id = id)")
    private String property2;

    @Formula("(select c from SOME_TABLE ST ST.some_id = id)")
    private Long property3;

    @Formula("(select d from SOME_TABLE ST ST.some_id = id)")
    private Long property4;

    .....
```

Comment: you have this problem because you use @Formula the wrong way, @Formula is supposed to be used for calculating or calling internal SQL function, like this `@Formula(value = “date_part(‘year’, age(dateOfBirth))”)`, and not for executing sql statements.
the problem you have have no solution but to scrap the @Formula

Comment: What does it mean no solution :) I don't have to use Formula, maybe there are other ways to do that, without Formula ?

Comment: Exactly, you need to scrap `@Formula` and another way like `@SecondaryTable`